# Zend Router Configuration

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm wondering if its even possible to use slashes in variables that are defined in Zend Router.

For example I have something like this

modules/
modules/default/
modules/default/controllers/
modules/default/controllers/OfferController.php

In OfferController.php I have action showAction()

And I have few offers in database that have unique url for example

**id**   |   **unique url**

1  | /url-1/

2  | /url-2/

3  | /url-2/still-url-2/

What I need is to search offers in showAction by url parameter that will be passed from link

Example of urls that i want to use:

http://example.com/offer/url-1/ - this will search offer with id 1

http://example.com/offer/url-2/still-url-2/- this will search offer with id 3

So its possible to configure Zend Router for my purpose?

Comment: So basically you want 'url-2/still-url-2' as a request parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer would be to say the URL should read: http://example.com/offer/url-2%2fstill-url-2/-

Also, from the [manual about Zend_Controller_Route_Route](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard) is says:

> Note: Character Usage The current implementation allows you to use any
>   character (except a slash) as a variable identifier, but it is
>   strongly recommended that one uses only characters that are valid for
>   PHP variable identifiers. Future implementations may alter this
>   behaviour, which could result in hidden bugs in your code.

But maybe you could have a look at the [Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex)